# complie cpp async program with mingw under windows

Tags: c++, asynchronous, mingw

this is example of using async in cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/.

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <future>       

bool is_prime (int x) {
  std::cout << "Calculating. Please, wait...\n";
  for (int i=2; i<x; ++i) if (x%i==0) return false;
  return true;
}

int main ()
{
  std::future<bool> fut = std::async (is_prime,313222313);
  std::cout << "Checking whether 313222313 is prime.\n";
  bool ret = fut.get();     
  if (ret) std::cout << "It is prime!\n";
  else std::cout << "It is not prime.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

when this code was compiled with minwg (gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0) the compiler showed this error:

```
15:21: error: variable 'std::future<bool> fut' has initializer but incomplete type
15 |   std::future<bool> fut = std::async (is_prime,313222313);
```

I would appreciate if tell what is problem.

Comment: *How* do you build? With what options? [I can't replicate the error](https://godbolt.org/z/G4c6zE47e).

Comment: I don't use any specific flag .> g++ main.cpp -o main

Comment: It works well https://ideone.com/qrvKq9

Comment: Try to add `-pthread` flag. If it doesn't help, you might want to install MSYS2 GCC packages with std::thread support. Those are based on MinGW-w64 of course, not MinGW.org, which as far as I know, does not have support for a lot more than only std::thread and std::future.

Comment: Not the cause, but I prefer this syntax, at least provide the policy as first value. 
 `std::future<bool> fut = std::async (std::launch::async, []{ is_prime(313222313); });`

Comment: As a workaround, why not use type-deduction with `auto`? As in `auto fut = std::async(...);`

Comment: Thank to all whom had concern. My problem has been solved by installing WinLibs build of GCC